# How to play a music of system (windows 7) in R?

Tags: r, windows

I am trying to call a music file (format .mp3) from my laptop and play it in R. My laptop has windows 7. I am using function `system()` but I can not play the music in R.
KMPlayer is an installed player on my laptop.
I want to play a music named `Don.mp3` which is saved in the following path on my laptop: `C:\Users\Vahid\Desktop`

My code is as follows:

```
system("KMPlayer/C:/Users/Vahid/Desktop/Don.mp3",wait=FALSE,ignore.stdout=TRUE)
```

but after running I receive the following error:

```
[1] 127
Warning message:
In system("KMPlayer/C:/Users/Vahid/Desktop/Don.mp3", wait = FALSE,  :
  'KMPlayer/C:/Users/Vahid/Desktop/Don.mp3' not found
```

Could someone please help me to solve this error and play my music in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TuneR` package:

```
library(tuneR)

file <-file.path('C:/Users/Vahid/Desktop/Don.mp3')
mp3 <- tuneR::readMP3(file)
play(mp3)
```

It also allows you to plot the audio signal:

```
plot(mp3)
```

[image]